# Rock Paper Scissors simple java using methods

Tags: java

So my task today is to make a rock paper scissors game using methods. My first problem with my code is that I need it to ask the user if they want to play again or not. (y or n) Also, I need to implement scoring, 1 point if user wins, -1 if they lose, and for each time they play again add that score to total score. Any ideas on how to implement this? or what I need to change to my code. Also I am a rookie so sorry for the ugly formatting and feel free to critic every little detail, ill soak up all the information I can.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
 boolean tie = true;
    do{
        String computer = computerChoice();
        String user = userChoice();
        tie = (computer.compareTo(user) == 0);
        determineWinner(computer, user);
    }while(tie);

  }

  public static String computerChoice( ){
  Random rand = new Random();
 int cinput = rand.nextInt(3)+ 1;
  String computer = "thing";
  if (cinput == 1)
  computer = "Rock";
   if (cinput == 2)
  computer = "Paper";
 if (cinput == 3)
  computer = "Scissors";
    return computer;
  }
  public static String userChoice(){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
  String user = "default";
  do{
    System.out.println("choose your weapon(Paper,Scissors or Rock)");
    user = sc.nextLine();
  }
  while (isValidChoice (user) == false);
  return user;
  }
  public static boolean isValidChoice(String choice){
  boolean status;
  if (choice.compareTo("Rock")== 0)
    status = true;
  else if (choice.compareTo("Paper")== 0)
    status = true;
  else if (choice.compareTo("Scissors")== 0)
    status = true;
  else{
    status = false;
    System.out.println("Error! Make sure you are capitalizing your                    choices");
}

return status;
  }
  public static boolean determineWinner(String computer, String user){
  System.out.println (" Computer Choice: " + computer);
  System.out.println ("Your Choice : " + user);
  if (computer.compareTo( "Rock" ) == 0 && user.compareTo  ("Scissors") == 0)
  System.out.println (" Computer wins! Better luck next time!");
  if (computer.compareTo("Scissors")== 0 && user.compareTo("Paper") == 0)
  System.out.println (" Computer wins! Better luck next time!");
  if (computer.compareTo("Paper") == 0 && user.compareTo("Rock") == 0)
  System.out.println (" Computer wins! Better luck next time!");
   if (computer.compareTo("Rock") == 0 && user.compareTo("Paper") == 0)
   System.out.println (" You win!!");
  if (computer.compareTo("Scissors") == 0 && user.compareTo("Rock") == 0)
  System.out.println (" You win!!");
  if (computer.compareTo("Paper") == 0 && user.compareTo("Scissors") == 0)
  System.out.println (" You win!!");
  else if (computer.compareTo(user) == 0 ){
    System.out.println(" Tie! the game must be played again.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
}
```

a output that my professor gave us as an example is:

```
Choose your weapon!
1. Paper
2. Scissors
3. Rock
5
 Choose your weapon!
 1. Paper
 2. Scissors
 3. Rock
  1
 You chose paper!
 I choose rock!
 I have been vanquished!
 We have matched wits 1 times, and your score is 1
 Do you want to play again (y or n)? y
 Choose your weapon!
 1. Paper
 2. Scissors
 3. Rock
 1
 You chose paper!
  I choose paper!
  We are equally matched. You are a worthy adversary.
  We have matched wits 2 times, and your score is 1
  Do you want to play again (y or n)? n
```

Comment: You know how to ask for a "weapon" repeatedly, but not how to ask to play again repeatedly?

Comment: Using .equals() would work better for checking for the response

Comment: @ScottHunter so I would just make another method and ask them to play again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the finished code. I added two functions, one to call the actual game and one to check if the player wanted to play again. Also, there is the concluding sentence in the end

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RPC
{
    public static Scanner   sc          = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int       score       = 0;
    public static int       gameCount   = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        play();
        while (playAgain())
        {
            play();
        }
    }

    public static void play()
    {
        String computer = computerChoice();
        String user = userChoice();
        determineWinner(computer, user);
    }

    public static String computerChoice()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int cinput = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        String computer = "thing";
        if (cinput == 1)
            computer = "Rock";
        if (cinput == 2)
            computer = "Paper";
        if (cinput == 3)
            computer = "Scissors";
        return computer;
    }

    public static boolean playAgain()
    {
        System.out.println("Play again?(y/n)");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        if (input.toLowerCase().equals("y"))
        {
            return true;
        } else if (input.toLowerCase().equals("n"))
        {
            return false;
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            return playAgain();
        }

    }

    public static String userChoice()
    {

        String user = "default";
        do
        {
            System.out.println("choose your weapon(Paper,Scissors or Rock)");
            user = sc.nextLine();
        } while (!isValidChoice(user));
        return user;
    }

    public static boolean isValidChoice(String choice)
    {
        boolean status;
        if (choice.equals("Rock"))
            status = true;
        else if (choice.equals("Paper"))
            status = true;
        else if (choice.equals("Scissors"))
            status = true;
        else
        {
            status = false;
            System.out.println("Error! Make sure you are capitalizing your choices");
        }

        return status;
    }

    public static void determineWinner(String computer, String user)
    {
        gameCount++;
        System.out.println(" Computer Choice: " + computer);
        System.out.println("Your Choice : " + user);
        if (computer.equals("Rock") && user.equals("Scissors"))
        {
            score--;
            System.out.println(" Computer wins! Better luck next time!");
        }
        if (computer.equals("Scissors") && user.equals("Paper"))
        {
            score--;
            System.out.println(" Computer wins! Better luck next time!");
        }
        if (computer.equals("Paper") && user.equals("Rock"))
        {
            score--;
            System.out.println(" Computer wins! Better luck next time!");
        }
        if (computer.equals("Rock") && user.equals("Paper"))
        {
            score++;
            System.out.println(" You win!!");
        }
        if (computer.equals("Scissors") && user.equals("Rock"))
        {
            score++;
            System.out.println(" You win!!");
        }
        if (computer.equals("Paper") && user.equals("Scissors"))
        {
            score++;
            System.out.println(" You win!!");
        } else if (computer.equals(user))
        {
            System.out.println(" Tie! the game must be played again.");
        }
        System.out.println("We have matched wits" + gameCount + "times, and your score is" + score);
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: the first class you have for my programming class we haven't gotten to the part in lecture to use classes, so I don't quite understand what they do/how they are used..@Fungucide

Comment: It's exactly like what you had in the original code, it calls the play() method which used to be you main method. Then it asks if the user wants to play again with the playAgain() method and then repeats until the user says no. Also the way that I formated my while loops are different. You use do{ ...}while(condition). This way is while(condition){ ...}, but it is essentially the same thing

Comment: i meant this class ----  public class RPC
        {
         public static Scanner   sc          = new Scanner(System.in);
          public static int       score       = 0;
         public static int       gameCount   = 0;

Comment: I made the variables public so that it would be accessible by all the functions. This way, I would be able to keep track of the score instead of having to pass the score consistently through the functions. I also added the class because I had to run the program to make sure that it worked. Also, have you actually compiled and ran a java program before?

Comment: Can you just add that to the main method and not have the class? or is that bad?

Comment: That is bad because you need a class in order to compile and run a java program. Also, read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html